# How should I take a latest folder and exclude old folder having same name while unzipping files in C#

Tags: java, c#, asp.net

1. This my code when I unzip all .exe files
2. I am working on a patch merger tool.
3. All folders have to get merge except 1 folder named as "gwt" <---- this folder have to be latest one from latest .zip file

   ```
   // Unzip all zip files

   foreach (string name in fileNames)
   {
       sw.WriteLine(name);
       string zipfilePath = textBox1.Text + "\\" + name;
       //ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipfilePath, textBoxUnzipRootFolder.Text);
       using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipfilePath))
       {
           foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
           {
               string unzipFileName = Path.Combine(textBox1.Text,
                   entry.FullName).Replace("/", "\\");
               string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(unzipFileName);
               if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
               if (entry.Name == "")
                   continue;

               entry.ExtractToFile(unzipFileName, true);
           }
       }
   }
   sw.Close();

   MessageBox.Show("Total " + fileNames.Count.ToString() +
           " zip files have been unzipped.");
   Close();
   ```

Comment: How do you determine latest folder if each one has a newer version of one file? What exactly is the problem? You could always create a temporary directory, unzip there, then programmatically decide what to move where.

Comment: @JakubFojtik I downloaded all latest zip files in one folder, each zip file has the same folder for example "Jakub" and in the folder "Jakub" there is a subfolder "gwt" and I want to merge every folder excluding that "gwt". Hope I explained well

Comment: OK which zip file is latest? The last one in string[] fileNames or the one with newest files? If you know before extracting, you can check each ZipArchiveEntry and prevent "gwt" from being extracted if it is not the latest. Or you could extract each zip into its own directory, then delete all "gwt" you don't like, then move all into one dir.

Comment: @JakubFojtik the last one in string is the newest file.